# Cannot scroll suggested duplicates when asking a new question

Tags: bug, ios-app, asking-questions, duplicate-suggestions

I cannot scroll the duplicate suggestions shown below the title when asking a new question to see whether there is one below the first four.  And when there is a possibility or two showing, I look at one and then the back arrow, instead of returning to my question, goes back to the list of questions.  I have to re-enter the question just to get the second dupe link.

- App Version: 1.6.5.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Cellular)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: What duplicate suggestions?

Comment: They appear above the body area.  Usually on the web version there are many in a scrollable box.  Here, it looks like there may be more but only four show and it won't scroll.

Comment: Do you mean the suggestions based on the title you see when asking a new question?

Comment: Since there are no others, yes.

Comment: Fair enough, but that wasn't clear to me

Comment: For your second point, that's working as intended, the question is minimized to a bar on the bottom which isn't a part of the main navigation so hitting back shouldn't take you to that, you just need to tap the minimized question to get back to it (on iPhone anyway, I don't have the app on iPad)

Comment: Probably the same.  Wouldn't be the first non-intuitive thing in this app.