# Allow to use latest version of the iOS-app via TestFlight

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

Currently I'm using iOS-app version `1.6.5.3` which I got via [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) app (used for testing purposes). For now it's latest version for testing.

As far as I see in another post (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295865/339911)) current version from AppStore is `1.6.5.4`.

Is it possible to push last public version of the app into TestFlight so you don't have to delete beta and install stable?

All I want is to have latest version of the iOS-app via TestFlight until it expires (60 days for each version).

**Update:**

Seems there's a problem with notifications for a new version of app. But also as far as I see:

- 1.6.5.4 (AppStore) was released on may 5;
- 1.6.6 (TestFlight) was released on may 10;

So there are five days while beta testers have version that older than other users have. I think this is a little bit odd.

Comment: Also... most recent version in TestFlight now is 1.6.6 :)

Comment: @Cai when did you get 1.6.6? I only have Email dated 27 apr for 1.6.5.3 from TestFlight. Don't have iOS device right now to check via TestFlight app.

Comment: Looks like the email for 1.6.6 never came through but TestFlight says it was [released on May 10th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQeFF.png)

Comment: @Cai will check in a few hours. Thanks.

Comment: @Cai I got update to 1.6.6 now. All notifications was been [enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59fuv.png), but I haven't been notified for 1.6.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two parts:

**Lack of notifications**

I'm not sure why a notification didn't go out, but I think it's a problem with TestFlight and new app versions.  Apple recently combined steps in the UI, so now rather than first submitting for approval, then having you go back to add and notify testers after the app has been approved, now you submit your app for approval with a list of testers and check a "notify" checkbox.

So far with the new TestFlight UI, I had only done build version bumps (1.6.5.1 -> 1.6.5.2), which are instantly approved by Apple, and it appears notifications have gone out instantly.  It's possible that the delay for review with 1.6.6.0 triggered a bug there.  None of that is under my control, however. Hopefully we won't see it with 1.6.6.1.

**Why no 1.6.5.4 to the testers?**

The only difference between 1.6.5.3 and 1.6.5.4 was updating MathJax CDN locations for both MathJax and MHChem.  There wasn't really a need to test it or a benefit for testers (other than testers who use the Chemistry site), so I just sent it to the store without also pushing it to TestFlight.  It was a one-off thing but I'll make sure to push the build to testers anyway if it happens again like this.